# Export records from Salesforce based on a CSV input

Tags: data-export

I have a report (.csv) from an external system with a list of 1000+ record ids. I'd like to extract information from this records in salesforce to another .csv file.

I know there are some workarounds, like converting this into a string and querying for some at a time or creating a new field and using the list to "upsert" something unique to this records and being able to extract.

But, is there a native way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a native way to retrieve objects based on Ids specified in a CSV file. You'll have to take one of the approaches you named, or something similar.

The most expeditious way route I'm aware of, without altering the data model, is to call the [sObject Collections Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_retrieve.htm) endpoint with a `POST` request. This allows you to request batches of up to 2,000 records at a time, specified by Id, and retrieve specific fields in the response.

You'll still have to write a script to batch your Ids and call the endpoint, but it'll be quicker and more structured than batching over the Ids to construct dynamic SOQL queries. In the latter case, you end up being limited to ~200ish records per query due to the 4000 character limit on the SOQL `WHERE` clause. (Provided you're issuing your queries over the API; as sfdcfox points out, the limit doesn't apply if you're binding an Apex collection, but the work you'd have to do to benefit from that is *probably* messier than just calling the API a couple of times).

Comment: In case you didn't know, in Apex, if you bind to a variable, the 4k where limit doesn't apply in the usual sense. `select ... from ... where id in :listOfIds`

Comment: I should have mentioned that, but I figured it would be more work for Fernando to convert CSV data into an Apex collection and then work that around to an extracted CSV than to just call the API.

Comment: +1 for the collections resource, as that is a nice way to retrieve the information (and to automate that in the future). Unfortunately, this returns values in a JSON structure. It would be fine for simple record information, but I need some parent and grandparent information as well. The work to convert that is actually more then the work to convert the CSV data into the collection.